# Using Adapter and Item Holder, Hide views from List View

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-viewholder

I want to show my text view as shown in Image Below, for which i have to 
      remove other Views (as I have taken a Text View, Image View and a Video View 
      in a single XML). I am using Item Holder to show my Text View, and 
      want to hide Video View and Image View together.
         I m trying to code but it is not working.

```
      itemHolder.textViewMessage = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.messageDetail);

    if (itemHolder.textViewMessage != null && messageBean.getMessage()!=null)
            {
               itemHolder.textViewMessage.setText(messageBean.getMessage());  // here i am showing my text messages.
                itemHolder.imageview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                itemHolder.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }

         [1]:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsKTL.png
         [2]:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYCMb.png
```

In images given above, I don't need extra space below text. 
          Here Image View  and Video View are showing extra space, which
          I want to get Invisible.

Here view.gone not Working

Comment: why you using listview go for recycler